# Removing a Duplicate Item from ListBox converted into a string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

I have an issue where, when I take the items from my `ListBox`, and convert them into a single-line string, it duplicates the last item. My goal is for it to take just the items from the `ListBox`, and convert it into a single line of text, seperated by commas (`,`).

It took me a while, but I found some code on [this thread](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=678275), and it works for the most part, but the last item is always duplicated when converted to a string. The code that I am using is:

```
        Dim item As Object
        Dim List As String
      
        ' Other unrelated code

        ' Credit: T0AD - https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=678275
        For Each item In Form1.ListBox1_lstbox.Items
            List &= item & ","
        Next

        'To remove the last comma.
        List &= item.SubString(0, item.Length - 0) 
        ' This is weird, but setting item.Length - 1 actually removes two characters.

        ' Add text to textbox
        TextBox1.Text = List
```

I have a feeling that it has to deal with the code that removes the comma, as it is an `&=` that calls the `item` Dim again. But I can't seem to figure out what to do.

An example of the output would be something like this: `Item1,Item2,Item3,Item3`

When I just want this: `Item1,Item2,Item3`

Comment: How about `String.Join(",", ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object))`? (Adjust the ListBox name as required.)

Comment: And the answer to why it's not doing what you want in the line `List &= item.SubString(0, item.Length - 0)`: you probably meant to write `List = List.SubString(0, List.Length - 1)`. (Also, `List` is a bad name for a variable as it makes it harder to read when you get used to `List(Of T)`.)

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I went with a more complex method of doing this. As for the List variable, I actually changed it for the example. I tried using a different `String.Join` method, but it caused it crash when I tried executing it. But this method works. As for the `List &= item.SubString(0, item.Length - 0)`, I actually meant to write it that was, as writing it with `-1` instead, it causes it to remove two characters, the comma, plus the last character in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this line.

```
List &= item.SubString(0, item.Length - 0)
```

You are adding another string to `List` with the `&=`. The string you are adding is the final value of `item` from the `For Each` loop.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ListBox1.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("There are no items in the list box.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim List As String = ""
    For Each item In ListBox1.Items
        List &= item.ToString & ","
    Next
    List = List.Substring(0, List.Length - 1)
    TextBox1.Text = List
End Sub
```

Additional solution provided by @Andrew Morton in comments, which doesn't require the ListBox to contain items.

```
TextBox1.Text = String.Join(",", ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object))
```